# HTML Elements to multiple servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have 2 JSP's pages as well as 2 servlets.
I want to get what ever the user enter in the username text box and store it in 2 scriptlets and then show it on the 2nd JSP page.

Example:

JSP Page 1

```
<input type='text' name=user>
```

Servlet 1

```
String userName = request.getParameter("user");
```

Up to this point im good I understand.
But what if I want to carry over that same value to in this case a 2nd servlet and then from that servlet display the same value to another jsp page?

I tried setting and getting the attribute like this,

```
request.setAttribute("userName", userName);

RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("SecondServlet");
dispatch.forward(request, response);
```

And then casting to string in the 2nd servlet how ever when I place that value in a scriptlet tag it does not display anything on the jsp page?

Comment: 1) Do **not** use scriptlets 2) Do use [`.tag` files](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html)

Comment: Maybe in the scriplet you are trying to get value from request.getParameter instead of request.getAttribute? Why don't you post your scriplet code as well.